# Blogdown theming not being picked up by github

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I have followed instruction from [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html) to get a GitHub static blog using markdown. However, a particular theme is not playing nice with it. The following MWE results in a unthemed blog:

```
blogdown::new_site()
file.create(".nojekyll")
blogdown::install_theme("lambdafu/hugo-finite")
```

Then editing the config.toml file to reflect my github.io domain.

Finally,:

```
blogdown::build_site()
cd public
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/lf-araujo/lf-araujo.github.io
```

Unfortunately these steps causes the creation of an unthemed website, see [here](https://lf-araujo.github.io/). I suspect it has to do with the custom theme.

- Does anyone suggest a way of debugging this error?

P.S.: blogdown::serve_site() generates a correctly themed preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your HTML output files (e.g. [index.html](https://github.com/lf-araujo/lf-araujo.github.io/blob/381e077ede26b7d00173ce0ddbc5c8c20b591488/index.html#L9)), you misconfigured your `baseURL` in `config.toml`. It should be `https://lf-araujo.github.io/` instead of `http://github.com/lf-araujo.github.io`. The `baseURL` option is documented in [Section 2.2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html) of the **blogdown** book.